# OpenFigi API curl to java POST

Tags: java, curl

i  am trying to convert the following curl to java  and i get the error 400

400     Request body must be an array.  The request body is not an array.

curl -v -X POST 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'
     --header 'Content-Type: text/json'
     --data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'

public void r2() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

```
    //String str = "https://www.openfigi.com/search#!?marketSector=Comdty";
    String str = "https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping";
    URL url = new URL(str);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/json");

    String input = "'[{\"idType\":\"ID_WERTPAPIER\",\"idValue\":\"851399\",\"exchCode\":\"US\"}]'";
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    /*
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }*/

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
}
```

thanks

Comment: It should work if you remove the `'` character in the beginning and ending of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

The program work as expected after removing the `'` character in the beginning and ending of `input`.

```
String input = "[{\"idType\":\"ID_WERTPAPIER\",\"idValue\":\"851399\",\"exchCode\":\"US\"}]";
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
```